# How to make a bash script that names files with today's date

Tags: bash, shell, script, bash-scripting

I'm trying to make a script to back up my we servers, but I have very limited knowledge with bash scripting. I want the script to name the backup file ht-"today's date". How would I go about doing that? Is it possible to use a command, like the date command, as a variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To backup directory `dir` into a file named after today's date and time:

```
name=$(date '+ht-%F-%H-%M-%S.tgz')
tar -czf "$name" dir
```

You may eventually want to use a program such as [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/), [dirvish](http://freecode.com/projects/dirvish), or one of their competitors.  These programs automate the process and also, via the use of hardlinks, save on disk space if you are keeping multiple backups.

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  I have a data logger that runs all the time creating the daily file called today.dat and have been having to be up at midnight every night to "mv today.dat Archive/2017-05-22.dat" before the master system scoops up all the archives after midnight.

Comment: @SDsolar So, I presume you use: `mv today.dat "$(date '+Archive/%F.dat')"`

Comment: Actually, I am using `mv today.dat Archive/$(date +%F).dat` now.

Comment: I also do the same for `today.png` files and it works to place the files in the `pngArchive` subdirectory.  So far, so good.  However, that same syntax doesn't seem to work in scp.  Like if I try to use `scp pngArchive/$(date +F%).png GATHER:Desktop/montage` to prepare my GATHER machine to produce montages.  It says it can't find the file named `+F%.png`

Comment: My workaround is to write-protect them then SCP the entire directory.  Next day when it runs, it finds all the files write-protected except the new one.  I used to use Korn shell many years ago, then C shell, then the strange VMUNIX shell on VAX machines.  This is my first time with bash.  So I am learning as I go.  (Funny that my definition of a N00B is someone born too late to have watched the moon landing live with the rest of the world)

Comment: @SDsolar Small changes can make a big difference.  Instead of `date +F%`, try `date +%F`

Comment: Yikes.  Gadzooks. Yes, of course that works.  Thank you!  It does help to actually understand why I am typing it so I won't make a copying error like that.